# Can file_get_content be used along with preg_replace?

Tags: php

How can I get the file content from preg_replace?

```php
<?php

function get($it) {
$r = array("~<script src='(.*?)'></script>~");
$w = array("<script type='text/javascript'>' . file_get_contents($1) . '</script>");
$it = preg_replace($r, $w, $it);
return $it;
}

$it = "<script src='/script.js'></script>";
echo get($it);

?>
```

It returns `<script type='text/javascript'>' . file_get_contents(/script.js) . '</script>`

Comment: You need https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php and get the file contents and build the replace text in the callback.

Comment: So what exact result do you want?

Comment: `preg_replace`  does not contain any "file content". What do you want to achieve? What is not working with the given code?

Comment: Currently, `file_get_contents` is just part of the string that you are building (it's inside the `"`) and so isn't processed as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path is relative as in your example the `file_get_contents` won't work but this should get you closer:

```
function get($it) {
    return preg_replace_callback("~<script src='(.*?)'></script>~", function($match){
        return "<script type='text/javascript'>" . file_get_contents($match[1]) . '</script>';
    }, $it);
}
$it = "<script src='/script.js'></script>";
echo get($it);
```